# pulling specific values from Angular 6 observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, ng-bootstrap

using Angular 6, i am making an API call that uses an interface like so:

Service:

```
   getEmployees(): Observable<Employees[]> {
    return this.http.get<Employees[]>(this.getEmployeesAPI);
  }
```

inside component:

```
    ngOnInit() {
        this.employeeService.getEmployees()
          .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
          });

      }
```

simple model interface:

```
export interface Employees {

  fullName: string;

}
```

the API response looks like this, where it's an array of objects, there are roughly 3900 of these 'user' objects inside the response.

```
[
{
"fullName": "Robert Jones"
},
{
"fullName": "Ian Cooper"
},
{
"fullName": "Jackie Jones"
},
{
"fullName": "Amber Smith"
}
]
```

I can easily use these in the template if i was displaying them in a table or other element type grid  like so:

```
{{ data.fullName }}
```

however what i need to do is grab JUST the list of values i.e. "the names". out of the observable so i can use them in a typeahead. the typeahead is NG Bootstrap  i've looked at several posts here on stackoverflow for two days and have yet to find the correct answer.

in the NG Bootstrap documentation they talk about doing a search from a service, however this kills the GUI and is not responsive, my idea was to prefetch the data, smoosh(technical term) them into an array (in mem) them use the type ahead on the local array.

Component Class:

```
 employees: Employees[];



  //kicks in when 3 characters characters are typed.
  employeeSearch = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      map(search => search.length < 3 ? []
        : this.employees.filter(v => v.fullName.indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) > -1).slice(0, 10))
    )
```

I've tried using map and pluck from rxjs, these were met with bad results.

Comment: You can use a chain of operators. Why didn't `pluck` work? It seems like a good fit for this. You can add a `filter` instead of checking for length in the `map` like `filter(search => search.length < 3`). It will be also a good idea to separate the search field and the results in different components (if possible) and use `Output` and `Input` to improve performance.

Comment: thanks for the advice !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you want to turn an array of objects into a simple array of strings.

Ideally you can do it with only `map`:

```
this.employeeService.getEmployees().pipe(
  map((employees: Employees[]) => employees.map(e => e.fullName)),
).subscribe(...);
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to do it more "Rx way" you can unpack the array into single emissions and then collect them back into an array:

```
this.employeeService.getEmployees().pipe(
  mergeAll(), // unpack the array
  pluck('fullName'),
  toArray(),
).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: correct, I need to turn the objects into an array of strings that only contain the names!  not sure about the double map above in your code?

Comment: when i try the first way you suggest, i get 'type string[] is not assignable to type Employees[]' error inside the subscribe method

Comment: You need to change return types because the two chains I showed above now emit `string[]` and not `Employees[]`.

Comment: Assuming you mean the return from the get<> ?

Comment: `getEmployees(): Observable<string[]>` ... or where ever you want to return that chain.

Comment: this works great! you saved me further hours of a headache!  marking as best answer - thank you !